# How can I change the edges with spacebars (Recrusiv) (JAVA)

Tags: java, recursion, tree

How can I change the edges with spacebars (without loops (for, while...) and lambda).

I have this Code:

```
    public static String prettyPrint(Node tree) {
        if(tree == null)
            return "";
        return "- " + tree.value + "\n" + prettyPrint(tree.left) + prettyPrint(tree.right);
    }
```

the return is:

```
- f
- o
- C
- tasty
- F
- E
- e
```

but it need to come out like this:

```
- f
  - o
    - C
      - tasty
    - F
  - E
    - e
```

(the tree: **f[o[C[tasty,null],F],E[null,e]]**)

i am not good with recursion, can you guys help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

- Added a counter to track the depth of tree.
- There are changes in parameter as could not use static int value as
  counter.
- There 14 spaces are present before hypen(-)
- In java could not multiply a string (but it is possible in python)
  that's why had to substring it.

```
    public static String prettyPrint(Node tree, int i) {
```

`if (tree == null)
   return "";


  return "              - ".substring(14 - i) + tree.value + "\n" + prettyPrint(tree.left, i + 1) + prettyPrint(tree.right, i + 1);
 }`